# Nexus 6 with developer preview no mobile data

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this but the mobile data 4G/LTE is not working on my nexus 6 and I think it is because of the beta preview of android nougat latest version announced today. When I was with marshmallow it was working fine but now even when I asked people in the store to set up the APN it is not working. 2G/3G also don't work but I can receive and give calls to other numbers. Anyone having the same issue?

**EDIT:** Turned out the problem was from the mobile operator. I should probably have checked that first.

Comment: Like you said, it's mostly because of the preview. There's often nothing you can do. Just wait for an update or go back to stable. Also, for this kind of questions there is another SE-Site: android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way I can move the thread there.

Comment: As far as I know no. But feel free to ask it there too. But I don't believe you will get any other answer than "go back to stable or wait". I know, it's sometimes hard to be a beta-tester :)